# neo4j-import multiple file import on windows

Tags: neo4j

Does the Windows version of neo4j-import accept multiple file imports? I get this PowerShell error. I tried with/without quotes and with several separators.

```
C:\tmp>neo4j-import.bat --into my.graphdb --nodes "artifacts_header.csv,artifacts1.csv"
Invoke-Neo4jImport : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ArgumentList'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:144
+ Import-Module 'C:\Users\wisa\Downloads\neo4j-community-3.0.1-windows\neo4j-community-3.0.1\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4jImport <<<<  --into my.graphdb --nodes artifacts_header.csv,artifacts1.csv)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4jImport
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Windows version of `neo4j-import` *should* accept multiple files in the way that you're trying to do it. However there is a bug which means that it doesn't work in Neo4j 3.0; we're working on a fix. As a workaround you should be able to put everything into a single file.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Because of the size,  merging the files wasn't a good option to me. I managed to get it working by starting the java class directly.