# Can we specify data types for properties while importing data using neo4j-import tool?

Tags: graph, neo4j

I've imported lot of data using neo4j-import tool only to be useless as the default data type is string for all columns. I'm not able to perform any aggregations on data. However, I'm able to change the data type using update commands but this is a lot of overhead.

Is it possible specify data types importing data itself using neo4j-import tool?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use toInt(), toFloat(), and toString(). If you need booleans, you can do a comparison to get a boolean output.

Ah, this is assuming that you have access to Cypher in the import.

If you're using the 2.2.0 (and probably 3?) import, you should be able to define the type in the header like so `propertyName:int`

See the [property types](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0/import-tool-types-labels.html#import-tool-property-types) part of the 2.2.0 import tool docs, and the [CSV header format](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0/import-tool-header-format.html) sections.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I'm not able to pass header file and data file separately in import tool. Some thing similar to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544375/neo4j-import-multiple-file-import-on-windows

Comment: Oh that seems to be a windows command prompt issue or something. Can't you have the header as the first line in your data file instead?

Comment: I'm not able to open the csv file because of large size. And if generate file along with headers I'll not be able to specify data types